# how to get fantasy nfl team data for login user using yahoo api

Tags: php, yahoo-api

i am working on a project where user can import his team into my website. using import roster from yahoo. i have create an app for fantasy sports data. i got login and got token from yahoo.but after getting token i am stuck that what api should i call which give me team list of current login user.below the code what i have tried till now.

```
<?php
/* Example code to access Gemini API: Fetch advertiser information, create a new campaign and read specific campaign data*/

require "YahooOAuth2.class.php"; #Download here: https://github.com/saurabhsahni/php-yahoo-oauth2/

/*Your Yahoo API consumer key & secret with access to Gemini data */

define("CONSUMER_KEY","*****************************");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET","*************************");
$redirect_uri="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];//Or your other redirect URL - must match the callback domain




$gemini_api_endpoint="https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2";

$oauth2client=new YahooOAuth2();

if (isset($_GET['code'])){
    $code=$_GET['code'];    
} 
else {
    $code=0;
}

if($code){
     #oAuth 3-legged authorization is successful, fetch access token    
     $token=$oauth2client->get_access_token(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,$redirect_uri,$code);


    #access token is available. Do API calls.    

     $headers= array(
                    'Authorization: Bearer '.$token->access_token,
                    'Accept: application/xml', 
                    'Content-Type: application/xml'
                    );

     //Fetch Advertiser Name and Advertiser ID
     $url="http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/teams/";

     $resp=$oauth2client->fetch($url,$postdata="",$auth="",$headers);

     var_dump($resp);
     die;


     //$jsonResponse = json_decode( $resp);
     $advertiserName = $jsonResponse->response[0]->advertiserName; 
     $advertiserId = $jsonResponse->response[0]->id; 
     echo "Welcome ".$advertiserName;

     //Create a new campaign
     $url=$gemini_api_endpoint."/campaign";
     $postdata='{
      "status":"PAUSED",
      "campaignName":"NativeAdsCampaign",
      "budget": 3000,
      "budgetType": "LIFETIME",
      "advertiserId": '.$advertiserId.',
      "channel":"NATIVE"
      }';

     $resp=$oauth2client->fetch($url,$postdata=$postdata,$auth="",$headers);
     $jsonResponse = json_decode( $resp);

     $campaignID=$jsonResponse->response->id;
     $campaignName=$jsonResponse->response->campaignName;

     echo "\n<br>Created a new campaign with ID: ".$campaignID;

     //Read specific campaign data
     $url=$gemini_api_endpoint."/campaign/".$campaignID;
     $resp=$oauth2client->fetch($url,$postdata="",$auth="",$headers);
     $jsonResponse = json_decode( $resp);
     echo "\n<br> Campaign object:<br>\n";
     print_r($jsonResponse->response);
}
else {
    /* no valid access token available, go to authorization server */
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Found");
    header("Location: " . $oauth2client->getAuthorizationURL(CONSUMER_KEY,$redirect_uri));
    exit;
}

?>
```

above code working fine but after login i am getting an error

```
Received error: 401 Raw response: Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="bearer_token_not_over_ssl", realm="yahooapis.com"
```

what i think either i am calling wrong api to get data . actually i read document but still not getting idea that what api should i call to get team data of login user.

Comment: that error means you didn't authenticate properly. That's entirely unrelated to whether it's the correct method to call in order to get the data you require, or not. Check the API docs for how you are meant to authenticate, and check that you provided the correct credentials.

Comment: i am login correct i am getting everything access token,refresh token and everthing what we need to call an api. when i change my api like this `$url="https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20fantasysports.games%20where%20game_key%3D%22238%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=";`  so i got response like `Received error: 400 Raw response:{"error":{"lang":"en-US","diagnostics":null,"description":"Authentication Error. The table fantasysports.games requires a higher security level than is provided, you provided ANY but at least USER is expected"}} `

Comment: well that seems relatively clear? You either simply don't have permission to that resource, or somewhere there is some sort of scope variable which you need to set to "USER". Again check the API docs for that method call.

Comment: no dear @ADyson i am on right way only not having idea about API. i am calling wrong URL after authentication.

Comment: well I can't really help you much with that, sorry, I don't know that specific API. I just understood what the original error message meant because it's quite generic. I think you should study the documentation to see what should be returned from each method and whether it contains what you need, or ask the people who created it for guidance.

Comment: ok thank you @ADyson